# Delete created Objects inside List

Tags: c++, string, list

I'm creating some Objects inside a loop and add it to a listwith:

```
list<MyObject> myList;    
MyObject* ob = new MyObject();
ob.setAttribute("whatever");
myList.push_back(*ob);
```

After the loop finishes, I'm using the list several times. 
I've started now a Leak Detector and saw, that I've to delete all the `MyObject` objects.

How I delete them properly (In the destructor?). Should I use a iterator? But how I get the real object - and not the iterator pointer?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that your list contains raw objects, not pointers to them.

Comment: That won't compile - you're trying to push a pointer into a list of objects. Unless you've got a good reason for faffing around with `new`, just do `push_back(Object())` and don't worry about memory leaks.

Comment: sorry - I wrote sample code in the question and forgot to add some details. I've modified it.

Comment: @Danny. Your leak is actually here: `myList.push_back(*ob);` As soon `ob` goes out of scope the object created on the heap is leaking. The push back took a copy of `MyObject`.

Comment: That's clear. I know where the leak is created. Is there no possibility to delete the objects in the destructor when I've only the list available?

Comment: @Danny.No, as mentioned you loose access to the `ob` pointer, as soon it goes out of scope. As also mentioned, you don't need `new` here at all.

Comment: @Danny: Of course not. The list contains copies of the dynamic objects, and has no idea where the originals might be. You'd need `delete ob` here, after copying it, to fix the leak (assuming you didn't feel like removing the `new` to fix it properly).

Comment: The objects in the list are a copy of the ones created with the new operator. Just do a `delete ob;` after the push_back. Actually, there is no reason to create the object in the heap. Just: `myList.push_back(MyObject()); myList.back().setAttribute("whatever");`. This is optimum since you avoid the creation of an unnecesarry object. Although a copy is done during the push_back, depending on MyObject it will be faster for an empty object than for an object with assigned values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason for dynamic allocation here, since the list stores objects by value. All you're doing is copying and discarding a dynamic object; it's leaked immediately since you don't keep a pointer to it anywhere. Just push objects directly, copying a temporary or automatic variable if necessary:

```
list<MyObject> myList;    
MyObject ob;
ob.setAttribute("whatever");
myList.push_back(ob);
```

If you did need to store pointers, perhaps for polymorphism, then you'd use smart pointers to avoid leaks:

```
list<std::unique_ptr<MyBase>> myList;
std::unique_ptr<MyObject> ob(new MyObject);
ob->setAttribute("whatever");
myList.push_back(ob);
```

If you really want to juggle raw pointers for some reason, then yes, you will have to delete them yourself. You really shouldn't try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete them, they're copied when added into the list by `push_back()`. But, you need to delete `ob` after you used it. Such as:

```
list<MyObject> myList;    
MyObject* ob = new MyObject();
ob.setAttribute("whatever");
myList.push_back(*ob);
delete ob;
```

Basically, you don't need to use pointer here, you can just declare `ob` in stack to avoiding the manual memory management:

```
list<MyObject> myList;    
MyObject ob;
ob.setAttribute("whatever");
myList.push_back(ob);
```

And, according to your program's requirment, you can use some kind of smart point to avoiding such manual memory management, such as:

```
list<std::shared_ptr<MyObject>> myList;    
myList.push_back(new MyObject);
...
// don't need to delete them manually
```